# python class initialization

Tags: python, class, initialization

Folks,

I am wondering if the following two definitions of the node class are the same or not?

```
class node:
    left = None
    right= None
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data


class node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right= None
```

Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

In the second definition, `node.left` and `node.right` don't exist. The `right` and `left` attributes would only exist on an initialized instance of the class. However, in the first definition, you can access `node.left` and `node.right` directly on the class; you don't have to instantiate it.

Comment: Also, you can run `node.left = 10` and every `node` instance would have `a.left == 10` (if you are using the first code chunk).

Comment: The values in the first class will be available when instantiated. They can even be set independently of the class values. So other than accessing them without instantiation both classes are more or less the same.